# Removing localstorage data from table row

Tags: javascript

I've been trying create like a Clear Cells button but I am not sure it's affecting the LocalStorage.  What is the best way to alter data (remove data) from all rows?

I am using this to pre-created fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ondras/hYfN3/
Here is what I have so far, this is controlled by a button just to test if one cell can be deleted.

```
function emptyIt()
{
   var form = document.getElementById("A1");
   form.value=0;
};
```

Comment: There's no automatic relationship between table cells and localStorage. If you want to update localStorage, you have to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check updated fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/hYfN3/1195/

and code is below for clearing all data with localstorage too. if you just want to remove localstorage you can comment other lines or for specific entry only then you can make condition for it also.

```
(window.calAll = function() {

INPUTS.forEach(function(elm){try{
    localStorage[elm.id] = "";
        DATA[elm.id] = "";
    elm.value = "";
}catch(e){}});
})();
```

You can check condition like

```
(window.calAll = function() {

INPUTS.forEach(function(elm){try{
    if(elm.id == "A1")
    {
    localStorage[elm.id] = "";
        DATA[elm.id] = "";
    elm.value = "";
    }
}catch(e){}});
})();
```

Comment: Wow that works perfectly, I like exception handling too.  Thanks I should be able to work with this.